# TextField update issue

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have 3 TextField components: price, taxRate and totalPrice.
I want to modify totalPrice when the price was change by applying the formula totalPrice = price * (1+taxRate/100).
I tried to change the value of totalPrice inside the OnChange function by changing this.state.selectedInvoice.totalPrice but the totalPrice Text field don't show the new value.
I figure out that the render function is not called after on change and i force calling with this.forceUpdate(). Nothing happen.
I don't have any idea of what I can do to change the value of the totalPrice.

Thank you in advice
Bogdan

P.S: 
I attached a small part of the code because all the code have 800+ lines

```
onChange(event){
   const target    = event.target;
   let   value     = target.value;
   //console.log(target);    
   let currentState    = Object.assign({}, this.state);
   let objectName      = target.name.split('.')[0]; // selectedInvoice
   let propertyName    = target.name.split('.')[1]; // value
   currentState[objectName][propertyName] = value;
   if(propertyName==="price") {
     console.log("Price...");
     currentState[objectName]['totalPrice'] = value*2 ;
     //When i save the state i expected to have the <TextField /> to be automatically rerender.
   }
   this.setState(currentState);
   console.log(currentState);
   this.forceUpdate() ; //This line is to force render method to run
}

render() {
    <div>
      <div className="row">
       <div className="col-xs-3">
        <TextField
            name              = 'selectedInvoice.price'
            defaultValue      = { this.state.selectedInvoice.price }
            onChange          = { this.onChange }
            hintText          = "Enter Plan price"
            floatingLabelText = "Price"
            floatingLabelFixed= { true }
            fullWidth         = { true }
            errorText         = { typeof this.props.invoicesStore.errors['price']==='undefined' ? '' : this.props.invoicesStore.errors['price'][0].message }
        />
       </div>
       <div className="col-xs-3">
          <TextField
            name              = 'selectedInvoice.currency'
            defaultValue      = { this.state.selectedInvoice.currency }
            onChange          = { this.onChange }
            hintText          = "Enter Currency"
            floatingLabelText = "Currency"
            floatingLabelFixed= { true }
            fullWidth         = { true }
            errorText         = { typeof this.props.invoicesStore.errors['currency']==='undefined' ? '' : this.props.invoicesStore.errors['currency'][0].message }
        />
       </div>
       <div className="col-xs-3">
         <TextField
            name              = 'selectedInvoice.taxRate'
            defaultValue      = { this.state.selectedInvoice.taxRate }
            onChange          = { this.onChange }
            hintText          = "Enter Tax Rate"
            floatingLabelText = "Tax Rate"
            floatingLabelFixed= { true }
            fullWidth         = { true }
            errorText         = { typeof this.props.invoicesStore.errors['taxRate']==='undefined' ? '' : this.props.invoicesStore.errors['taxRate'][0].message }
        />
       </div>
       <div className="col-xs-3">
           <TextField
            name              = 'selectedInvoice.totalPrice'
            defaultValue      = { this.state.selectedInvoice.totalPrice }
            onChange          = { this.onChange }
            hintText          = "Total Price"
            floatingLabelText = "Total Price"
            floatingLabelFixed= {true}
            fullWidth={true}
            errorText         = { typeof this.props.invoicesStore.errors['totalPrice']==='undefined' ? '' : this.props.invoicesStore.errors['totalPrice'][0].message }
        />
       </div>
    </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: you should provide some code, because setstate should work just fine in general. it depends on how you use it and we can't tell what's wrong with your code if we can't see it :)

Comment: I received a negative vote because i didn't show any "research effort".. I searched on google before posting. I take step by step and tried to debug with console.log(). I figure out that onChange calling the render function is not called, for this reason, after i research i find o way to force component rendering by calling this.forceUpdate()...... Even if the state value of the object have the correct value the component value didn't change. I dont have big experience with react and i tied a lot of things before posting.

Comment: I post the code on : https://jsfiddle.net/8goy9js5/ because i have limited characters.

Comment: I wasn't the one who down-voted the question but i do think it lacks code example. Instead of jsfidfle you can add a snippet inside your question with react running and show exactly what the problem you are facing. [This is how you attach a react snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/3148807)

Comment: is `TextField` a component you wrote? is there a reason why you use `defaultValue` instead of `value` like a normal `input`?

Comment: Thank you. I solve the issue. . TextField is not written by me. Is from materil-ui component.

Answer (score 0):

I use material-ui module and solution for this issue is to use value instead defaultValue. As a mention i have to forceUpdate when i user this solution because without doing that the components are not updated.